# Unallocated partition is not visible for arch installation

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, dual-boot, kernel-panic

I am trying to install Arch linux on my laptop. I had allocated 150GB partition to be used as arch partition.
after booting from usb drive and connecting to the internet, I've attempted to do the partitioning but there wasn't any free space visible. I have to mention that i've tried fdisk, cfdisk, lsblk and parted.
fdisk and parted and lsblk showed all partitions except unallocated one.
cfdisk only showed bootable usb.
I tried gparted and it worked, but after 2 attempts for installing Arch, all ended up to emergency shell and kernel panic(after rebooting and choosing arch from the grub) so arch didn't boot at all.
I attempted to install ubuntu after that and everything was fine so as the free space partition visibility.

- The laptop is UEFI.
- Hard drive is GPT.
- I am trying to use Arch along with Windows 10 with dual booting.
- EFI partition has 100MB size.[image]

Comment: Please post `fdisk -l` output.

Comment: @artem-s-tashkinovv  just uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to mention that i've tried fdisk, cfdisk, lsblk and parted. fdisk and parted and lsblk showed all partitions except unallocated one.

Free space is just free space, tools like `fdisk` or `lsblk` don't show it, these show only existing devices/partitions. You have a free space between your 4th and 5th partition -- approximately 153 GiB: check the difference between end sector of `nvme0n1p4` and start of `nvme0n1p5`. To add a new partition (or multiple partitions if you need more for the Arch installation) simply use `fdisk /dev/nvme0n1` and then `n` for a new partition, `fdisk` will help you to select the correct start and end for the new partition.

Comment: your point is valid but why cfdisk and parted are not showing the free space?